# How to removes/clear files from cache (Added Expires Headers in htaccess file)

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, header

This is my .htaccess file in which I have added expiry headers for archive caching and page speed in my website.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

But after some days I need some modifications in my files, so I just modified my files, but not single files are reflecting due to this expiry headers. All the time I get old files. So I decided to remove code given above from .htaccess. but after removing code there is no result. I have also clear all browser data many times, but no result.

So I just want to know that how to clear all cache from browser/server which is cached by setting expiry headers.

My website is running on the apache+php server.

Answer (score 7):

Ah yes, I have gone through this myself! What I used was the following in my `.htaccess`, place it at the top:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

What this does is basically force your cache to re-validate every time somebody accesses it.

When you access it for the first time after putting in this code. Simply refresh your page and it should push the re-validation.

Comment: can u please tell me that what code given in your answer exactly do? Because what I want is to just clear all cached files which are cached by this expiry headers code in .htaccess.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer. It forces the `cache-control` to re-validate every time it is accessed. Meaning it will reset the cache every time you (or a user) access the website. You would only keep this code in while you're making changes.

Comment: Is there any way to set expiry headers like if any file changed then automatically reflect on site. without removing its expiry from htaccess?

Comment: I think it is possible. But not through `.htaccess`. You would need to use JavaScript.